# ExecuteScalar can not find stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

I use the library "Dapper" to connect with MS Sql.

When I call stored procedure, it show error message

> can not find stored procedure.

But stored procedure it already exist in Database.
How can I resolve this problem? thanks.

```
public static string WrtoLogDb(string id, string id1)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connStrTest))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            var strf33_schD = conn.ExecuteScalar<int>("exec DelClsCourTimeTest", new { id,  id1 }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return strf33_schD.tostring();
        }
        catch (Exception EX)
        {
            return EX.ToString();
        }
    }          
}
```

Comment: Unless Dapper does something odd, if you're saying the `CommandType` is stored procedure, I'd expect you to just provide the procedure name - not an `exec` statement.

Comment: Have you tried prefixing your stored procedure? I can't remember exactly what it is but it's something like `dbo.DelClsCourTimeTest`.

Comment: What schema is your stored procedure in?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever：I try it , now is OK

Comment: Worst error handling ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `CommandType` is set to `StoredProcedure` then the `CommandText` should just be the procedure name, in your case `"DelClsCourTimeTest"`.